# GSEventSetBacklightLevel from a plist value iPhone

Tags: iphone, floating-point, plist

I'm trying to set the backlight display from a plist value, but I keep getting an error! So I guess my question is how can I convert a plist value to a float value so I can set the backlight form the plist entry?

**The Code:**

```
float customBacklight = (float)[[plistDict floatForKey:@"Backlight Level"] floatValue];
GSEventSetBacklightLevel(customBacklight);
```

**The Error:**

```
reason: '*** -[NSCFDictionary floatForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15695c0'
```

**Everything works fine, values are correct, Private API's are setup correctly, just cant seem to convert the plist value to a float value. This is not for an AppStore release either.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float customBacklight = [[plistDict valueForKey:@"Backlight Level"] floatValue];
```

Comment: Well, not for some reason it works using this method, thanks.